# How to Send the Viewstate String, asp page values Via Httppost

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post

I have a code written in python which send's in the viewstate and the formvalues in this way

send('_*VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE0MDM4Mz.........%2BhFiTeLDMyk...................&*_EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWA....I%2.................mtK6HmOBny%2............NHcX5PO4r9oSpA&TextBox1='+payload+'&Button1=click\r\n')

where the dots stand for the rest of the string. Now i want to send this by httppost from android. I'm not able to understand how to translate the above code to httppost, i tried making the `__VIEWSTATE`,`__EVENTVALIDATION` as key's and the string's as value but that did not work. How can i send it ?? how do i send the above string as it is via httppost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do this**:

```
private static final String DATA = "_VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE0MDM4Mz.........";  

public String send() {
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(new URI("<your POST uri>"));
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", DATA));
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = handler.handleResponse(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call the send() method from a background Thread.